# Why every countably compact space is $s-$ separated?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

[image]

I know that every countable metric space is compact metric space and Every compact metric space is totally bounded and complete. That is for any $s$ there is an $s-$net(A subset of $X$). That is for any $s$, for each $x\in X$ there is $p\in$ $s-$net such that $d(p,x)<s$. I don't understand how the underlined statement is coming. please explain.

Comment: A countable metric space, in the sense that as a set it is countable, needn't be compact. Take the rationals.

Comment: Is a set of rationals is countably compact?

Comment: If by countably compact you mean that every countable open cover has a finite subcover, then it is not countably compact. No unbounded metric space can be countably compact.

Comment: hey! please do visit the chat once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by Zorn's lemma.  Consider the poset $P$ of all subsets $A\subseteq X$ such that $d(a,b)\geq s$ for all $a,b\in A$, ordered by inclusion.  A union of chain of elements of $P$ is again an element of $P$, so every chain in $P$ has an upper bound.  By Zorn's lemma, $P$ has a maximal element.

Comment: How to prove that there exist such set for all $s$?

Comment: How do I prove that $P$ is non-empty?

Comment: You don't have to prove that $P$ is non-empty.  In any case though that follows immediately from the fact that every chain has an upper bound, since the empty set is a chain.  Concretely, $\emptyset\in P$ (and indeed that is the upper bound that the proof constructs for the empty chain).

Comment: You mean for some $s$, $P$ have only had an empty set?